# How to find the correlation coefficients on a matrix of scatterplots in R?

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot

I am using R coding. Given data with three columns of various x-values and one column of y-values for a scatterplot, I created a 4x4 matrix of scatterplots using the command:

```
plot(info45)
```

(I named the table of information "info45".) I also saw in this YouTube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FS9E907bbcA that you can use the command pair(info45) and this worked just the same.

Following the example in the above video, I wanted to find the correlations of the scatterplots. I entered the command:  `cor(info45)`  but it returns the message `"Error in cor(info45) : 'x' must be numeric"`. I am not sure if this helps, but the column headers in the data table are V1, V2, V3, and V4. In fact, here's a sample of the data table itself:

```
       V1     V2     V3     V4
1      X1     X2     X3      Y
2  14.620 226.00  7.000 128.40
3  15.630 220.00  3.375  52.62
4  14.620 217.40  6.375 113.90
...
```

What command(s) should I enter to get a matrix of correlation coefficients as the speaker does in the video?

Comment: You've screwed up and created a dataframe or matrix with either factor or character values. That first line: "1 X1 X2 X3 Y", should not be there. You probably should reload the data from disk and use `header=TRUE` in the read.table call. (Also read `?read.table`)

Comment: The original data was in Excel so I removed the first row's data and now it is all numbers. This completely solved my problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With insight from [DWin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/dwin) (1st comment on the question), I went into where the original data was stored (Microsoft Excel) and completely removed the first row. This removed the headers from the data set and allowed R to run computational commands. It also affected the appearance of my scatterplot matrix.

Note: Remember that after changing the data in Excel, the file should be saved as a .txt file, text(tab delimited) so that R can read it. The file should then be re-read into R (just enter it again as before).